# Updating activity from service and onResume gives different results

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I'm trying to update a ProgressBar in my Activity.

I set up a BroadcastReceiver to trigger the change.

The function that does the actual change in the activity:

```
private void updateStepProgress(Intent intent){
    int steps = intent.getIntExtra(Keys.EXTRA_STEPS, MainApp.getInstance().daySteps);
    ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    Log.d("STEP_UPDATE_ACTIVITY", steps+"");
    progress.setProgress(steps);
}
```

I'm sending the intent from my Application object:

```
public void updateSteps(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(StepCounterManager.UPDATE_STEP_UI_EVENT);
    intent.putExtra(Keys.EXTRA_STEPS, daySteps);
    Log.d("STEP_UPDATE_MAIN", daySteps+"");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

I'm calling the update like this:

```
MainApp.getInstance().updateSteps();
```

When calling update from a service, it shows the correct value, but when calling it from the Activity's onResume, it shows the value that was there when the Activity was first created.

Logs from service (correct values):

```
03-30 11:43:10.243 24523-24523/ee.greaton.tervis:StepServiceLock D/STEP_UPDATE_MAIN: 1255
03-30 11:43:10.248 24468-24468/ee.greaton.tervis D/STEP_UPDATE_ACTIVITY: 1255
03-30 11:43:10.442 24523-24523/ee.greaton.tervis:StepServiceLock D/STEP_UPDATE_MAIN: 1256
03-30 11:43:10.448 24468-24468/ee.greaton.tervis D/STEP_UPDATE_ACTIVITY: 1256
```

Logs from onResume right after (1245 was the value when the Activity was created):

```
03-30 11:43:12.049 24468-24468/ee.greaton.tervis D/STEP_UPDATE_MAIN: 1245
03-30 11:43:12.074 24468-24468/ee.greaton.tervis D/STEP_UPDATE_ACTIVITY: 1245
```

The value gets changed in onSensorChange in the Service just before updating the Activity:

```
MainApp.getInstance().daySteps = value;
```

What is causing it and how to get correct values in onResume?

Comment: So, where/when does `daySteps` get incremented?

Comment: Added to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty clear what's happening:

```
03-30 11:43:10.442 24523-24523/ee.greaton.tervis:StepServiceLock D/STEP_UPDATE_MAIN: 1256
03-30 11:43:10.448 24468-24468/ee.greaton.tervis D/STEP_UPDATE_ACTIVITY: 1256
```

You can see here that the `Service` and the `Activity` are running in 2 separate processes (in the logcat, the 3rd column contains the process ID and the thread ID). Since you have 2 separate processes, you have 2 separate instances of the `Application` object.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Removed android:process from service declaration in manifest to make it work.